# Cannot generate swagger with multiple HttpPut commands

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I can't get swashbuckle to generate the swagger.json when I have more than one HttpPut command. I am using OData4 and ASP.NET Core 2.2. If I comment one of either of the two HttpPut methods, it generates just fine. I have tried adding [SwaggerOperation(OperationId = '')] attribution and that was unsuccessful. I have tried adding [ODataRoute(nameof())] attribution and that was unsuccessful. I have tried editing the [HttpPut(nameof())] attribute and it didn't work. I am at my wits end trying to figure out the key combination to allow this to work. Any suggestions are eagerly welcomed.

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ODataRoutePrefix("Items")]
public class ItemsController : ODataController {
     [HttpGet]
     [Produces("application/json")]
     [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<Item>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
     [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
     [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = Select | OrderBy | Top | Skip | Count, 
        AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.None, 
        AllowedArithmeticOperators = AllowedArithmeticOperators.None, 
        AllowedLogicalOperators = AllowedLogicalOperators.None,
        AllowedOrderByProperties = "name,location",
        MaxOrderByNodeCount = 2, 
        MaxTop = 100)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {
      ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("({key})")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Item), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(string key) {
       ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] AddItemCommand command) {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StopMonitoring([FromBody] StopMonitoringCommand command) {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeMonitoring([FromBody] ChangeMonitoringCommand command) {
        ...
    }

}
```

With both HttpPut methods in there, it fails with an "Fetch error undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json" error message.

Comment: Open that `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` it should give you more details... But I will advise against multiple HttpPut on one controller, just move the second to another controller or a different action

Comment: @HelderSepulveda That's likely where my thinking is wrong. If you have multiple actions, are they simply HttpPost methods with different routes rather than HttpPut? I can't seem to find examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HelderSepulveda and the [Actions and Functions in OData v4 Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions) gave me the clues to resolve this issue.

Regardless of whether they are `HttpPut` or `HttpPost` on the controller, actions can be added by adding them to both the controller and OData model configuration.

e.g.

```
public class ODataModelConfiguration : IModelConfiguration {
    public void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder, ApiVersion apiVersion) {
        builder.EntitySet<Item>("Items");
        builder.EntityType<Item>()
            .Action("StopMonitoring")
            .Parameter<StopMonitoringCommand>("command");
        builder.EntityType<Item>()
            .Action("ChangeMonitoring")
            .Parameter<ChangeMonitoringCommand>("command");
    }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
[HttpPut]
[ODataRoute("StopMonitoring")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> StopMonitoring([FromBody] StopMonitoringCommand command) {
    ...
}

[HttpPut]
[ODataRoute("ChangeMonitoring")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeMonitoring([FromBody] ChangeMonitoringCommand command) {
    ...
}
```

Combined with the code in the original post, this generates the following in swagger:

```
GET  /api/Items
POST /api/Items
GET  /api/items({key})
PUT  /api/items/StopMonitoring
PUT  /api/items/ChangeMonitoring
```